# Rendering from command line gives different results from drivers. How to prevent that?

Tags: drivers

I have a blender file that has 4 different scenes in it.
Each scene is a row of cubes that is animated using drivers to make them rotate based on the position of an empty. By moving the empty I control the rotation of all the cubes simultaneously. In the drivers expression I use "hash(self.name)" to create some random variation between each cube.

It works exactly as I want it to. But I'm using a bat file to batch render the 4 different scenes that are contained in the same blend file, and when I do, the animation of the cubes is different from when I render directly from Blender. It appears that the random variation changes, like the seed of the randomness changed.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem, and if so, how can I prevent that from happening?

By the way, I am using Eevee as the render engine (don't know if that's relevant).

Comment: Hmmm, never tried something like this - my first thought would be to use some constant to create variation. For example giving each object a different _Pass Index_ number and reference this in the drivers. Or a custom property... depends on how the values are used in the driver or in which range they should be...

Comment: That might be a solution. Although I would like some solution that wouldn't require to manually change a value in each object, something more automated. But if there's no way, I think this will have to do.